# How to find out the dates of the different financial quarters (e.g. Q1, Q2, etc.)?

Tags: time-series

**Question:** Is there any resource I can use to find a list of dates which constitute the start and end of the 'financial' quarters (e.g. Q1, ..., Q4) for the years 2006 onwards?

I know sometimes they are arbitrary, but just wondering whether there is any resource, because I couldn't find those from a quick internet search.

Thanks

[EDIT]: This would be for the US (equity) markets. I am not specifically looking for APIs, but would be open to using them (am also happy just to see some basic list).

Comment: Just some comments: Do you have a specific market (with corresponding business day calendar) in mind? Also: are you looking for an API or some such?

Comment: In what country ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses - this is for the US (equity) markets. I'm not specifically looking for APIs, but if those are also available then I would be keen to know. I'll update the question now to reflect this

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to figure out when a U.S. corporation's fiscal year ends? The 10K will most often say "For the fiscal year ended December 31, 2022" (so fiscl 1Q coincides with calendar 1Q) but some corporations choose to use different dates.

Comment: It's not 'arbitrary', it depends on how the company in question has defined it.  The data source you're using should have a field that specifies this.